# Flowbite Swippable bottom drawer not working in nextjs 13 with tailwind css

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13, flowbite

I'm creating an app that needs Flowbite Swippable edge drawer (https://flowbite.com/docs/components/drawer/#swipeable-edge) in nextjs 13 page. When I'm trying to drawer the swippable action does not work. I've tried to check console errors by logging them, but it does not shows any error or warnings with drawer.

Here is my code:

```
export default function DrawerLayout({ params, searchParams }) {

    console.log(params, searchParams)
    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen">
            

            <div className="text-center">
                <button className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-drawer-target="drawer-swipe" data-drawer-show="drawer-swipe" data-drawer-placement="bottom" data-drawer-edge="true" data-drawer-edge-offset="bottom-[60px]" aria-controls="drawer-swipe">
                    Show swipeable drawer
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="drawer-swipe" className="fixed z-40 w-full overflow-y-auto bg-white border-t border-gray-200 rounded-t-lg dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 transition-transform bottom-0 left-0 right-0 translate-y-full bottom-[60px]" tabIndex={-1} aria-labelledby="drawer-swipe-label">
                <div className="p-4 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700" data-drawer-toggle="drawer-swipe">
                    <span className="absolute w-8 h-1 -translate-x-1/2 bg-gray-300 rounded-lg top-3 left-1/2 dark:bg-gray-600"></span>
                    <h5 id="drawer-swipe-label" className="inline-flex items-center text-base text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 font-medium"><svg className="w-4 h-4 mr-2" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                        <path d="M6.143 0H1.857A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 0 1.857v4.286C0 7.169.831 8 1.857 8h4.286A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 8 6.143V1.857A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 6.143 0Zm10 0h-4.286A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 10 1.857v4.286C10 7.169 10.831 8 11.857 8h4.286A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 18 6.143V1.857A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 16.143 0Zm-10 10H1.857A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 0 11.857v4.286C0 17.169.831 18 1.857 18h4.286A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 8 16.143v-4.286A1.857 1.857 0 0 0 6.143 10ZM17 13h-2v-2a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v2h-2a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2v2a1 1 0 0 0 2 0v-2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2Z" />
                    </svg>Add widget</h5>
                </div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 p-4 lg:grid-cols-4">
                    <div className="p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 22 21">
                                <path d="M16.975 11H10V4.025a1 1 0 0 0-1.066-.998 8.5 8.5 0 1 0 9.039 9.039.999.999 0 0 0-1-1.066h.002Z" />
                                <path d="M12.5 0c-.157 0-.311.01-.565.027A1 1 0 0 0 11 1.02V10h8.975a1 1 0 0 0 1-.935c.013-.188.028-.374.028-.565A8.51 8.51 0 0 0 12.5 0Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Chart</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 14">
                                <path d="M18 0H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2ZM9 6v2H2V6h7Zm2 0h7v2h-7V6Zm-9 4h7v2H2v-2Zm9 2v-2h7v2h-7Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Table</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700 lg:block">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 14 20">
                                <path d="M13.383.076a1 1 0 0 0-1.09.217L11 1.586 9.707.293a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L7 1.586 5.707.293a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L3 1.586 1.707.293A1 1 0 0 0 0 1v18a1 1 0 0 0 1.707.707L3 18.414l1.293 1.293a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 0L7 18.414l1.293 1.293a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 0L11 18.414l1.293 1.293A1 1 0 0 0 14 19V1a1 1 0 0 0-.617-.924ZM10 15H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Zm0-4H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2Zm0-4H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="hidden font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Ticket</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 18 20">
                                <path d="M16 1h-3.278A1.992 1.992 0 0 0 11 0H7a1.993 1.993 0 0 0-1.722 1H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v15a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-3 14H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h8a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Zm0-4H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h8a1 1 0 1 1 0 2Zm0-5H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h2V2h4v2h2a1 1 0 1 1 0 2Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">List</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
                                <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M5 2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v8a1 1 0 0 1-1 1M2 5h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v8a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1Zm8 5a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Price</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 18">
                                <path d="M14 2a3.963 3.963 0 0 0-1.4.267 6.439 6.439 0 0 1-1.331 6.638A4 4 0 1 0 14 2Zm1 9h-1.264A6.957 6.957 0 0 1 15 15v2a2.97 2.97 0 0 1-.184 1H19a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-1a5.006 5.006 0 0 0-5-5ZM6.5 9a4.5 4.5 0 1 0 0-9 4.5 4.5 0 0 0 0 9ZM8 10H5a5.006 5.006 0 0 0-5 5v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h11a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2a5.006 5.006 0 0 0-5-5Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Users</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700 lg:block">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 18">
                                <path d="M6.5 9a4.5 4.5 0 1 0 0-9 4.5 4.5 0 0 0 0 9Zm-1.391 7.361.707-3.535a3 3 0 0 1 .82-1.533L7.929 10H5a5.006 5.006 0 0 0-5 5v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h4.259a2.975 2.975 0 0 1-.15-1.639ZM8.05 17.95a1 1 0 0 1-.981-1.2l.708-3.536a1 1 0 0 1 .274-.511l6.363-6.364a3.007 3.007 0 0 1 4.243 0 3.007 3.007 0 0 1 0 4.243l-6.365 6.363a1 1 0 0 1-.511.274l-3.536.708a1.07 1.07 0 0 1-.195.023Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Task</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-700">
                        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-2 mx-auto mb-2 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-600 rounded-full w-[48px] h-[48px] max-w-[48px] max-h-[48px]">
                            <svg className="inline w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M4 12.25V1m0 11.25a2.25 2.25 0 0 0 0 4.5m0-4.5a2.25 2.25 0 0 1 0 4.5M4 19v-2.25m6-13.5V1m0 2.25a2.25 2.25 0 0 0 0 4.5m0-4.5a2.25 2.25 0 0 1 0 4.5M10 19V7.75m6 4.5V1m0 11.25a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 0 4.5 2.25 2.25 0 0 0 0-4.5ZM16 19v-2" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div className="font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Custom</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is an image of issue:
[image]